# Get data from google analytics api in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I am trying to develop a form abandonment heat mapper

```
function newMarkup(id, uniqueHits){
var min = Math.min.apply(null,uniqueHits);
var max = Math.max.apply(null,uniqueHits);
var med = max / 2;
for(var num = 0; num < id.length; num++){
    styleElement(id[num], uniqueHits[num], min, max, med);
}}

function styleElement(element, value, min, max, med){
    var el = $("[id$=" + element + "]");
    if(el.prop('nodeName') === "INPUT"){
        if(value == max){
            el.addClass('very-good');
        }
        if(value < max && value > med){
            el.addClass('good');
        }
        if(value == med){
            el.addClass('average');
        }
        if(value < med && value > min){
            el.addClass('not-so-good');
        }
        if(value == min){
            el.addClass('poor');
        }
    } else {
        el = el.next();
        if(value == max){
            el.addClass('very-good');
        }
        if(value < max && value > med){
            el.addClass('good');
        }
        if(value == med){
            el.addClass('average');
        }
        if(value < med && value > min){
            el.addClass('not-so-good');
        }
        if(value == min){
            el.addClass('poor');
        }
    }
}
```

and I am wondering if it is possible to do the call to the api from a chrome extension?

Essentially I am trying to do this call to get the data:

```
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:uniqueEvents',
    'dimensions': 'ga:eventLabel',
    'sort':'-ga:uniqueEvents',
    'filters': "ga:eventCategory==Form Field Tracking - /join"
})
```

I tried do create my heatmapper by having an iFrame in an MVC web application but because of the trouble of trying to send data across domains, I gave up on that.

I would like to know if it's possible to get data from the analytic's API from a chrome extension? I'd imagine it would have to be done in a similar fashion as how google scripts uses the analytics API (using a service account) but I have been unable to find any documentation or find out if this is even possible.
(Example of code in scripts)

```
function runReport(profileId) {
    var today = new Date();
    var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, Session.getTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(today, Session.getTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var tableId  = 'ga:' + profileId;
    var metric = 'ga:uniqueEvents';
    var options = {
        'dimensions': 'ga:eventLabel',
        'sort':'-ga:uniqueEvents',
        'filters': "ga:eventCategory==Form Field Tracking - /join"
    };
    var report = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, metric, options);
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help or advice anyone has for me. I am trying to query the google analytic's API from a chrome extension. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you took a look for what can do extensions ? What you are asking is not really easy to do with extension I don't understand why you want to use extensions. By the way the first code (with tons of if) Can largely be improved. Because it's not very readable has it is

Comment: I haven't really had chance to go over my colouring in code as of yet as it's a bit more important for me to get the data from GA, the main importance of this post is the API calls... I want to be able to do it in a chrome extension so I can manipulate the DOM of the page while I am on it

Comment: The official documentation [provides a tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics) on using GA in an extension. I see lots of similar quesions with answers. It's hard to suppose you haven't searched but how is your problem different? Specify it in the question.

Comment: That is to TRACK, 
I want to call the API to get data... 
The question is very specific about what I want? I want to be able to query the API from a chrome extension, not track the hits from the extension, I think you read the question wrong.

Comment: I see. Well it seems like the standard task to execute a script that needs access to an external server, see [CSP remote script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script) section in the documentation. So basically include the GA script with your extension, reference it from your background page, add CSP rule to manifest and call the API.

Comment: also the posted code looks like apps script. if so then comment on why its there.

Comment: The apps script was just an example from the scripts app, I'm just trying to colour in the input's with the data received from the google API call, but I as of yet can not see any way to get it to work from an extension. I don't even know if this is possible? I can see from the answers so far that no one else has ever tried anything like this before?

Comment: @wOxxOm No, I couldn't figure out how to get it into the content script and allow calls from the extension, if anyone has any other way apart from an extension to be able to do this than I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm very new to extensions and have only just started looking into them the past 2 days for this project, would you be able to point me in the right direction for what it is I'm after? Would I be alright messaging you directly as you seem to have the answers I'm after?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested on GA specifically but this is the general method of working with scripts that require external server for the API:

1. The content script can't make requests to other sites so it should ask the background page to do it by [sending a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage)
2. The background page includes `ga.js` script referenced in the manifest, this file must be present in the extension, it's not a remotely loaded script.
3. The background page can communicate with the external API server after we add the [corresponding CSP rule](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script) (added in the manifest)
4. Now the message from step 1 is received by the background page listener, which invokes GA and sends the results back to the content script of the original tab (`tabId` was saved when the first message was received).

---

- manifest.json:

  ```
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "run_at": "document_start",
          "all_frames": true,
          "js": ["content.js"]
      }
  ],
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js", "ga.js"]
  },
  "content_security_policy": 
      "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
  .............
  ```
- content.js:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "getGA", data: some_data_for_GA});
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      if (msg.type == "GA") {
          // apply msg.data to the page elements
          ...................
      }
  });
  ```
- background.js:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
      var tabId = sender.tab.id, frameId = sender.frameId;
      if (msg.type == "getGA") {
          gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
              ..................... // use msg.data if needed
          }).execute(function(response) {
              sendMessageToFrameId(tabId, frameId, {type: "GA", data: response});
          });
      }
  });

  function sendMessageToFrameId(tabId, frameId, msg) {
      // 1. frameId works since Chrome 41 and throws on prior versions
      // 2. without frameId Chrome 45 sends the message to wrong tabs
      try { chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, msg, {frameId: frameId}); }
      catch(e) { chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, msg); }
  }
  ```